# spark wildcard for directory of many files is very slow on startup

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd, glob

I am facing https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-8437 but when using a glob. When reading a directory with around 50k files of sizes up to 1.5mb like:

spark hangs for around 7 minutes before actually starting to process any work.

```
spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles("/path/to/folder/*", parallelism)
```

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?
Actually, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8437 describes the same problem but without a wildcard.
The first link mentions that it might not be sparks problem but rather has something to do with the Hadoop apis.

Comment: Well 1.5MB seems very small, the more files you have the longer the startup. If you're using HDFS you should really aim to have files close the block size, say 128MB, which would give you about 600 files. I would write a job to merge the files into a set of larger ones.

Comment: I know, thats why I have these on an edge node on a local file system. Instead I could put a couple of zip files into hdfs. You are probably right.

Comment: I will post an follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322914/spark-read-zip-file-which-contain-multiple-files-with-cpu-intensive-parsing as I have problems parsing the zip files properly.

Comment: If i was doing this, i wouldn't go near zip files. I would just write a simple job to merge the text files into a smaller set, of larger compressed files.

Comment: I originally get zip files. They are of this format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid and thus can't nicely be merged like a csv. I am thinking about preprocessing them in NiFi and writing the already parsed data as parquet to hdfs.